# What is the Captain Rocket graphics style?

Tags: style-identification

There’s a game on the App Store called [Captain Rocket](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/captain-rocket/id978918786?mt=8) and I love the graphics style, is there a name for this style so that I can do a bit of research in to it?

Here’s a couple of screenshots from the App Store:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Thanks

Comment: Hi Adam Carter, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site! For the design itself, this is basically **Flat Design**.

Comment: I was hoping for something more specific, the colours seem like they might be a more specific type of flat design. Thanks though

Comment: Generally called "Flat Design" http://www.awwwards.com/flat-design-an-in-depth-look.html

Comment: It's pretty much the definition of flat design

Comment: Flat design with some google-material-design-esque elements.

Answer (score 0):

That is all flat design. The rocket itself has a horizontal score, and the buttons have a drop shadow.